# Reading tar file content without writing on disk using java

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have tar file.I need to read the tar file content and do some logic on those content.This tar file might contains different file formats like xml,xslt,txt.
Need to read only xml files and use that content to do some business logic.

I am using Apache Commons library to read content of tar file.But its first writing the content on local disk and then read the content.Is it possible to only read tar content without writing on local disk.

```
public void untar(){
        final List<File> untaredFiles = new LinkedList<File>();
                InputStream is;
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

                final TarArchiveInputStream debInputStream = (TarArchiveInputStream) new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream("tar", is);
                TarArchiveEntry entry = null;
                int offset;
                 Map<String,Map<String,String>> filteredMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();
                    while ((entry = (TarArchiveEntry)debInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                            final File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
                            if (entry.isDirectory()) {

                                if (!outputFile.exists()) {

                                    if (!outputFile.mkdirs()) {
                                        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Couldn't create directory %s.", outputFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {

                                if(entry.getName().contains("test.xml")){

                                   final OutputStream outputFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); 
                                    IOUtils.copy(debInputStream, outputFileStream);
                                    outputFileStream.close();


                                    Map<String, String> defectXmlMap=   ConfigXMLParser.parseXML(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                    if(!defectXmlMap.isEmpty()){
                                        filteredMap.put(outputFile.getAbsolutePath(), defectXmlMap);    
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            untaredFiles.add(outputFile);
                        }
                    System.out.println("Final Filtered Map :"+filteredMap);
                    debInputStream.close(); 
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("File Not Found Exception occured");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IOException Exception occured");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ArchiveException e) {
                    System.out.println("ArchiveException Exception occured");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        In above code if I comment below block I can't read the content of the xml.

        final OutputStream outputFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); 
        IOUtils.copy(debInputStream, outputFileStream);
        outputFileStream.close();
    }



public static Map<String, String> parseXML(String tarFilePath){

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                        DocumentBuilder builder;

                        Document xmlDoc = null;
                        Map<String, String> testMap = null;
                        Map<String, String> mismatchMap = null;

                        try{
                            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                            xmlDoc = builder.parse(tarFilePath);

                            XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

                            XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

                            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(
                                    "/tests/testg/@environment", xmlDoc,
                                    XPathConstants.NODESET);

                            testMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            mismatchMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            String environment = "";
                            String testURL  = gettestingURLByEnv("TEST",xmlDoc,xpath);
                            System.out.println("TEST URL :"+testURL);
                            String testEnvURL  ="";
                            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                                 environment = nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                                 if(!"TEST".equals(environment)){
                                     testEnvURL = gettestingURLByEnv(environment, xmlDoc, xpath);
                                     if(routEnvURL.equals(testURL)){
                                         mismatchMap.put(environment, testEnvURL);
                                     }
                                 }
                            }
                            System.out.println("Mismatched Entry :"+mismatchMap);
                        }catch(Exception exp){
                            exp.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return mismatchMap;
        }
```

Comment: "I am using Apache Commons library to read content of tar file.But its first writing the content on local disk and then read the content.Is it possible to only read tar content without writing on local disk." Which apache commons library are  you using? commons-compress with `TarArchiveInputStream` does not write to disk. Maybe you're using it the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. There actually are no methods in TarArchiveInputStream that write to disk, so your code must be doing that.
Please show us your code, so that we can try to see where you went wrong

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek added my code.I need to read the tar file content and do some logic on it.

Comment: Right. So everywhere in your code that you write to a file, don't. Write to some sort of in-memory data structure instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that would read contents of all the files from the archive:

```
TarArchiveInputStream tarArchiveInputStream = new TarArchiveInputStream(
        new GzipCompressorInputStream(inputStream));
TarArchiveEntry tarArchiveEntry = null;
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
try {
    while ((tarArchiveEntry = tarArchiveInputStream.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
        System.out.println(tarArchiveEntry.getName() + ": " + (tarArchiveEntry.isFile() ? "F" : "D"));
        if (tarArchiveEntry.isFile()) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tarArchiveInputStream));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(tarArchiveEntry.getName() + ": " + line);
            }
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (bufferedReader != null) {
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```